# How to display group name in ag-grid before fetching data from API

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have a list of items in json format returns from restful api

```
{legalEntity:"embr",description:"embr desc",amount:400}
{legalEntity:"ana",description:"ana desc",amount:20}
{legalEntity:"wi",description:"wi desc",amount:10}
```

There are supposed to be many columns, I omitted them for simplicity.

In ag-grid, the data should grouped by legal entity.
So I define the columnDef to be

```
columnDefs = [
{headerName:'Legal Entity',field:'legalEntity',enableRowGroup:true}
{headerName:'Description',field:'description'}
{headerName:'Amount',field:'amount'}
```

Since enableRowGroup on legalEntity field is set to true, the grid groups data by embr, ana, wi. There should be more legal entity types when more data is inserted some day. However, ag-grid only display groups only from data it fetched. 
How do I put more types of legal entities and make it fixed in grid even when 0 item of that legal entity type exists in json results?

To give an example. Given columnDefs and the json would generate the grid like this

```
Group | Legal Entity | Description | Amount 
> embr     
         embr           embr desc   400 
> ana      
          ana            ana desc    20 
> wi 
           wi             wi desc    10 
>zone3 
>zuna 
(please note zone3 and zuna are not folded, just no item under the groups)
```

legal entity zone3, zuna I want them to display in the grid even no item is in the json. Current configuration does not show these two rows since they do not exist in json.

This is a little off topic, but to give some background. The reason zone3 and zuna should appears in the grid is there is also another button, after selecting node zone3, then pressing that button should generate a new item under zone3, same applies to zuna.

Comment: enableRowGroup allows a column to be grouped, whereas this rowGroup: true actually groups the data. is that something you are looking for?

Comment: @PratikBhat this only display groups based on data it fetched, say if no legal entity of embr on the list, the grid would be grouped only by ana and wi. I also want "embr" on the list even 0 item under it.

Comment: @PratikBhat I attatched an example

Comment: Can you generate a stackbliz

Comment: @honunu since ag grid as of now supports only grouping on data that is actually on the grid. You will have to most like mashup the data and add dummy rows to your rowdata. If it is fixed like zone3 or zuna. I would probably push these 2 empty elements to my rowData array. If this is something that should be dynamic, then I would make 2 api calls - one to get these grouping data not available in json and other call to get the actual data

Comment: @cedverd I'll try generate one

Comment: @PratikBhat I did try to add dummy rows, then under each group, there exist one empty row with columns all blank, looking weird.